# cURL command return the 400 Bad request error

Tags: python, postgresql, curl, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I use the postgres to fetch data from postgres database. So create flask api but when I use curl command it retuns 400 bad request error.
Here is my code -

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, Response
import psycopg2
import csv
import json
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor
import requests

conn = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='postgres' user='postgres'")
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def index():
    cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
    query = request.form['query']
    cur.execute(query)
    return Response(json.dumps(cur.fetchall(),indent=2),mimetype='application/json')

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0')

conn.close()
```

I use this curl command -

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/ -d '{"query":"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usage"}'
```

So how to use curl with flask api.

Comment: `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/ --data-urlencode query='SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usage'` is all you need. It'll do a `POST` request with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type. Your endpoint already expects form data and a `POST` method.

Answer (score 1):

### Disclaimer:

You have direct SQL injection. I suggest you fix.

### Answer:

That isn't how requests work. If you want to pass data in a `curl` the parameters need to be formated like a query string. It will not decode JSON for you. You have a few options.

### Fix curl:

(Note, I encoded the parameter in each of these)

Reformat curl to use GET parameters:

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/?query=SELECT%20COUNT(*)%20FROM%20usage'
```

Reformat curl to POST as expected:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/ -d 'query=SELECT%20COUNT(*)%20FROM%20usage'
```

This will let you get the data above as you've written it.

### Parse the JSON

This will let you keep using your cURL as you've written it:

```
# this is the short version, provided by randomir in the comments.
query = request.json().get('query')

# This is an alternative which roughly does the same thing
dat_str = request.data
dat_dict = json.loads(dat_str)
query = dat_dict['query']
```

Comment: No need for `-X GET` in second example, since `-d` defaults to `POST` and OP's endpoint already handles the `POST` method. Also, no need to set `application/json` content type header.

Comment: Also, no need to manually encode your query, just use `--data-urlencode` in place of `-d`.

Comment: And what's the point of parsing JSON, when your example sends invalid JSON data? BTW, if you really want to read JSON body, all you need is `query = request.json().get('query')`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this later as I did. I got the same error using a similar get request while trying to test my webhook receiver. I solved it by changing the curl request from:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://xxx.x.x.x:5000/ -d '{"key": "value"}'
```

to

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://xxx.x.x.x:5000/ -d "{\"key\": \"value\"}"
```